# Server Migration fatal error on contact forms in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, migration

I've been trying to pick my way through this error but I feel like I'm getting nowhere.

We're in the process of migrating a website from one server to another. All pages seem to work on the new site except for the contact form pages which appear to be trying to use 'form_helper.php'. These pages work correctly on the old server but not on the new one. I get an error of:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Loader::is_loaded() in C:\DATA\XXXX.com\www\application\helpers\form_helper.php on line 1038

Line 1038 of form_helper.php has the following on it:

```
if (FALSE !== ($object = $CI->load->is_loaded('form_validation')))
```

Any ideas would be GREATLY appreciated as I'm not that familiar with CodeIgniter.

Thanks in advance...

EDIT:

So I've worked out how to seemingly fix it... If I comment out the following code in the form_helper file, the page loads with no error:

```
    /*if (FALSE !== ($object = $CI->load->is_loaded('form_validation')))
    {
        if ( ! isset($CI->$object) OR ! is_object($CI->$object))
        {
            return $return;
        }

        return $CI->$object;
    }*/
```

Is this a bad idea? The full function now looks like this:

```
if ( ! function_exists('_get_validation_object'))
{
function &_get_validation_object()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();

    // We set this as a variable since we're returning by reference.
    $return = FALSE;

    /*if (FALSE !== ($object = $CI->load->is_loaded('form_validation')))
    {
        if ( ! isset($CI->$object) OR ! is_object($CI->$object))
        {
            return $return;
        }

        return $CI->$object;
    }*/

    return $return;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you open up form_helper.php and look what is on line 1038? maybe the php version?

Comment: I sure did, question updated.

Comment: Have you checked whether the `Loader`class inside system/core/ has a `is_loaded`method? Also, the default form_helper.php file should be located in system/helpers - I notice you have one in application/helpers/

Comment: There is no 'is_loaded' method inside the Loader class, but the same file works on the old server...

Comment: what version of CI are you using? by any chance is there a variable `$CI =& get_instance();` existing in the file?

Comment: 2.0.2 I think. And yes, please can you take a look at the just updated question?

Comment: Does the old server have an older version of CI compared to the "new" install? Because the latest CI version definitely has a `is_loaded`method inside the `Loader`class.

Comment: Nope, the files have literally been copied and pasted from one server to the other :/

Comment: I would upgrade your current CI-install to the latest version (2.1.4) - perhaps in a test-folder first. It's good practice to begin with, and not that time consuming anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have moved any array values in application/config/autoload.php from $autoload[‘plugins’] to $autoload[‘helpers’] or you will notice stuff break.

Comment: I have no $autoload['plugins'] in that file, I think that was an older version of CodeIgniter wasn't it? I have: 
     $autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','messages_validation','email_client','email_brokers','html2','analytics');

Answer (score 0):

is_loaded() function is defined in Code/common.php   Make sure the function is in right place.